# Custom Filter operator RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-android, rx-java2, reactive

I'm trying to embrace the glory of RxJava and integrating it into my apps. I have written the following code for adding comics whose cumulative cost is not more then the defined budget. To achieve this, I have written 2 implementations.

1. Uses `Observable.create()` which is discouraged mostly because of complexities with Subscriptions and backpressure
2. Uses already available operators in RxAndroid lib.

I would love to get feedback on which implementation is a better one in terms of performance, memory consumption and simplicity if put Subscription and Backpressure handling aside in `Observable.create()` for a moment?

**FIRST IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
Observable<Integer> filterObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Integer> e) throws Exception {
        Timber.d("filterComicsAccordingToBudget():subscribe");
        int pageCountOfComicsWithInBudget = 0;
        double totalCost = 0.0;
        for(MarvelComic comic : getMarvelComicsList()) {
            totalCost += Double.valueOf(comic.getPrice());
            Timber.d("totalCost: %s budget: %s priceOfComic: %s", totalCost, budget, comic.getPrice());
            if(totalCost > budget) {
                break;
            }
            pageCountOfComicsWithInBudget += Integer.valueOf(comic.getPageCount());
            Timber.d("pageCount: %s price: %s comicName: %s totalPages: %s", comic.getPageCount(), comic.getPrice(), comic.getTitle(), pageCountOfComicsWithInBudget);
            e.onNext(pageCountOfComicsWithInBudget);
        }
        e.onComplete();
    }
});

filterObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
        int comicCount = 0;
        int pageCountOfComicsWithInBudget = 0;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Timber.d("filterComicsAccordingToBudget():onSubscribe");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer pageCountOfComicsWithInBudget) {
            Timber.d("filterComicsAccordingToBudget():onNext");
            comicCount++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.e("onFilterComicsForBudget:onError() %s", e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Timber.d("filterComicsAccordingToBudget():onComplete");
        }
    }
});
```

**SECOND IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
Observable.fromIterable(getMarvelComicsList())
    .map(new Function<MarvelComic, HashMap<String, Double>>() {
        HashMap<String, Double> myMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        double count = 0;

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, Double> apply(@NonNull MarvelComic marvelComic) throws Exception {
            myMap.put("price", Double.valueOf(marvelComic.getPrice()));
            myMap.put("pageCount", Double.valueOf(marvelComic.getPageCount()));
            myMap.put("comicsCount", count++);
            return myMap;
        }
    })
    .takeWhile(new Predicate<HashMap<String, Double>>() {

        double sum;

        @Override
        public boolean test(@NonNull HashMap<String, Double> map) throws Exception {
            Timber.e("sum is: %s", sum);
            return (sum += map.get("price")) < 5.00;
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Observer<HashMap<String, Double>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(HashMap<String, Double> map) {
            Timber.e("value in onNext is: %s %s %s", map.get("pageCount"), map.get("price"), map.get("comicsCount"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.e("onError()!!!   %s",e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Timber.e("onComplete()!!!");
        }
    });
```

I kinda fancy the first implementation since it's more imperative which I'm used to and seems less clunky to me but then I may be completely wrong considering my limited knowledge in RxJava.

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid to create custom `Observable` for this kind of operations. You can do all you need using the normal RxJava operators.

On fly I would do something like this:

```
private Observable<Double> getLimitObservable(final double budget) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(getMarvelComicsList())
          .scan(0D, (aDouble, marvelComic) -> aDouble + marvelComic.getPrice()) 
          .takeWhile(aDouble -> aDouble < budget)
          .skip(1);
}
```

The above code use the `scan` (also called accumulator) operator for keeping track of the total amount of the prices of the comics. More detail [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html). So, now a double (representing the total amount) is returned from the new Observable. After this we have the `takeWhile` that stop the emission of the item until the condition remains true. Eventually I skipped the first item because the abovementioned Observable will emit at least one item (before the condition can be verified).

```
Observable.zip(getLimitObservable(500d), Observable.fromIterable(getMarvelComicsList()), (aDouble, marvelComic) -> marvelComic)
                .subscribe(marvelComic -> Log.d("test", "comic: " + marvelComic.getName()));
```

Now I combine the previous observable with a new one (using the zip operator) that will generate a new item for each couple of items (one from the first observable, and one from the second) and in this way you will get a number of items equal to the minimum number of items emitted from the two observables. More details [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

This will print the list of the first comics in the list, until you reach the budget limit.

I bet there are better solutions, but this is just an example.

Comment: Why wouldn't you go with the second Implementation I have written? What are the descripencies in the "Second Implementation" written in OP

Comment: I think that creating local variable inside the predicate is not a good idea (it doesn't seem functional): you can use the operators that will do the work for you. Moreover I don't understand the use of the `HashMap` in this context.

Comment: Also I would note that using `getMarvelComicList()` inside `.create()` is not very extensible. For example, one day you might decide to receive it from server as `Observable<Comic>` - and it will be hard to change with your first implementation. Having your second one or what @GVillani82 has proposed is better in this regard, would be a rather simple adjustment.

Comment: @GVillani82 If you could provide an explanation for your code and each operator's purpose in this snippet that would be amazing and will help me out tremendously in learning

Comment: Thanks @GVillani82 for the nice explanation but you missed the reason why I created Hashmap in the first place. I need all the three values in HashMap once the budget is reached. One way would have been iterate over the iteratable until the budget is reached and then write another observable to iterate over the list again to calculate the pageNumbers.

Comment: Indeed in my implementation, the subscriber receives a `marvelComic` object, so that you can get all the info that you need.